# Any way to set a passcode for the APK while deploying?

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk, passcode

I am working on xamarin.forms android application. I am wondering to know is there any deployment area when we can provide a password for each installment of the application. So, that user can use the application after the successful entering of the password that will be set at the deployment time.

in brief: A application will be provided to the user for which the password will be set while deploying. So, after installing the application the user will be asked to enter the password when user enters the correct password i.e used at time of deploying then only he can able to access the application.

Please let me know is there anything that make my requirement to work.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

The best way to protect your app is to implement an authentication system inside your app

Comment: @sahithi Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.